# Working with 64-bit ints and hexes in 32-bit perl

Tags: perl, 64-bit, hex

I want to write a perl script to parse text files with a lot of 64-bit integers in it. All integers are written in hex.

I need to

- Read hexes from input
- Compare 64-bit ints (`<`, `=`, `>`)
- Subtract 64-bit ints
- Output 64-bit hexes

I need to use 32-bit perl and I can't use any CPAN/external module (the script must be portable).

PS my perl is 5.8 (and this is minimal version which will be used for the script)

PPS bignum/ bigint errors:

```
$ perl -e 'use bignum; $_=hex("0x0000123412345678")'
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at -e line 1.

$ perl -e 'use bigint; $_=hex("0x0000123412345678")'
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at -e line 1.
```

PPPS: no `from_hex` here.

```
$ perl -e 'use Math::BigInt; $_=Math::BigInt->from_hex("0x0000123412345678");'
Can't locate object method "from_hex" via package "Math::BigInt" at -e line 1.
```

And no `qw/hex/`:

```
$ perl -e 'use bigint qw/hex/; $_=hex("0x0000123412345678")'
unknown option hex at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/bigint.pm line...
```

PPPPS: but new() works:

```
$ perl -e 'use Math::BigInt; $_=Math::BigInt->new("0x0000123412345678"); print  $_->as_hex(),"\n";'
0x123412345678
```

Comment: per the error in your update.  the `hex` function is only automatically upgraded by bignum in perl 5.9.4 or later.  You need to either explicitly export the `hex` function (which will be global in your version of perl) or use the `Math::BigInt->from_hex(...)` function directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The core pragma [bigint](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html) will let you transparently work with integers larger than your system can support.  There are associated functions in the [Math::BigInt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html) core library to convert from and to a hex representation.

Comment: I got "Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at" when I tried to use "`use bignum;`"

Comment: The pragma may be introducing too much magic and might be mangling some of your constants.  Try using the `Math::BigInt->new(...)` constructor directly.

Comment: How `Math::BigInt->new` will set the sign?

Answer (score 4):

[Math::Int64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aInt64) gives access to native signed and unsigned 64-bit numbers. This is surely faster than possible alternative [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aBigInt).

It has hex conversion routines, and it overloads comparison and arithmetic operators, so it can do everything you asked for.

```
use Math::Int64 qw( hex_to_uint64 uint64_to_hex );
my $n1 = hex_to_uint64("200000000");
my $n2 = hex_to_uint64("300000000");
printf("n1 is %s equal to n2\n",     $n1 == $n2 ? "" : "not");
printf("n1 is %s less than n2\n",    $n1 <  $n2 ? "" : "not");
printf("n1 is %s greater than n2\n", $n1 >  $n2 ? "" : "not");
printf("0x%016s", uint64_to_hex($n2 - $n1));
```

Output:

```
n1 is not equal to n2
n1 is less than n2
n1 is not greater than n2
0x0000000100000000
```

The use of CPAN or lack thereof doesn't effect the portability of the script.

Comment: The error is "`$ perl -e 'use Math::Int64; '                      Can't locate Math/Int64.pm in @INC`". As it was said in question, I can't use CPAN.

Comment: @osgx, No, you said you couldn't use CPAN for portability reasons, witch is inherently false.

Comment: In my case, the target PC has no CPAN (and internet) access at all and it is very hard to install some new module to it (there is no compiler at the target PC, as it is embedded; but there is a perl 5.8 on it). I can bring a single perl script, which will use no XS/C.

Comment: @osgx, That's not a portability issue, but it does make Math::BigInt a better answer for you. (Note that I don't actually know how portable Math::Int64 is, so there could actually be portability issues.)

Comment: I mean portable in a bit unusual way. The target is not a x86/x86_64, so it is not about usual desktop/notebook portability between win/lin/mac and gcc/llvm/icc. Most C codes are not very portable for my case. I dont know this too, but there was last comment about adding support of mingw32/win, so I think it is truly unportable for me)